# how to find duplicate data in sql in with different group

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, duplicates

Have a look at below set of data:

```
date                 group  tty  deposit no. 

12/30/2011 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 3 | 000131
08/02/2012 00:00:00 | C03   | 4 | 000131
11/13/2013 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 7 | 000131
12/10/2013 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 7 | 000131
11/30/2011 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 9 | 012040
11/30/2011 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 9 | 012040
11/30/2011 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 9 | 012040
11/30/2011 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 9 | 012040
11/30/2011 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 9 | 012040
11/30/2011 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 9 | 012040
11/30/2011 00:00:00 | HQ01  | 9 | 012040
```

As you can see, deposit number 000131 belongs to different group and terminal(tty). This deposit number supposed to be unique. Only can be use once for a group+terminal. Btw, deposit number can have more than 1 lines for THAT group+terminal. If a group+terminal already use a deposit number, another group+terminal cannot use the same deposit number.

Question: **how do I run query so the output will display the duplicate deposit number if exist, for different group + terminal?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GROUP BY with HAVING COUNT() > 1:

```
SELECT "deposit no." 
FROM table1
GROUP BY "deposit no." 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT group || '++' || TO_CHAR(tty)) > 1
```

What I did is counted the distinct values of `group` and `tty` combinations